# Implementing External data source and External objects

Tags: lightning-connect

Is  there any examples other than the one in youtube ,which explains about External data source and external objects.Is it possible to get the details of another salesforce org like details of account  using this feature?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, the "forward looking statement" safe harbor caveats apply to this response. :-)

External objects are currently (June 2014) in a limited pilot with plans currently to go to beta in Summer 14. If you are interested in using this feature, you should reach your AE or Customer Success contacts and see about enrolling in the pilot.

I just checked my pre-release org, and currently there doesn't appear to be anything that would enable or use this feature. If the plans for beta do follow through into reality, I would expect some parameters in your org setup to enable this, along with a user/developer guide to assist you with implementing it.

Comment: Hi peter you are right.I have contacted the support team to enable this feature ...though they have enabled it,I couldn't try this as per the salesforce video in you tube.I think i need for some more time to get completely working feature.

Comment: For pilot features, I would suggest that stack exchange may not be the best forum for help, as very few people typically participate. Please contact me privately: pchittum@salesforce.com. I can do some checking for you what has been enabled.

Comment: I just watched the [JavaScript Integration with Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/JavaScript_Integration_with_Visualforce) live webinar yesterday where examples using External Objects code were used. Great presentation. Code available from the webinar in JoshBirk's and VarDodla's Gists right now.